# How to prevent adding items that are already present in list in sencha touch 2.0

Tags: android, list, filter, sencha-touch-2

Hello guys I have a list in which I am adding list items dynamically.

Here's my code to add items in my store:-

```
    var re = record.get('Name');
    console.log('re:-'+re);
    if(!this.selGroup){
        this.selGroup = Ext.create('MyApp.store.selStore');
        console.log("created");
    }
    this.selGroup.add({Name: re});
```

It is adding items in the list perfectly but the problem I am facing is that add() method also add items which is already present in the list. I know I have to put filter to prevent to add items which is already present but I am not getting a way to do it.

Please suggest something useful to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess it's doing that because Sencha Touch thinks that `{Name: re}` is a new record. Why don't you just do: `this.selGroup.add(record)`, that way ST won't add duplicate records..

Here's an example: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#M8EgO